# MySQL to JSON using PHP and Joining Tables to create Nested Multilevel Arrays

Tags: php, mysql, json, parsing

i have a music sharing script and i am trying to create JSON from my mysql database, I'm trying to create a specific structure and can't seem to figure it out

heres my code

```
<?php
    //Create Database connection
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost","UN","PW");
    if (!$db) {
        die('Could not connect to db: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Select the Database
    mysql_select_db("DB",$db);


{  // <--WHY

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY username ASC"); 
    $json_response = array(); //Create an array
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $row_array = array();
        $row_array['idu'] = $row['idu'];
        $row_array['username'] = $row['username'];
        $row_array['first_name'] = $row['first_name'];
        $row_array['last_name'] = $row['last_name'];
        $row_array['country'] = $row['country'];
        $row_array['image'] = $row['image'];
        $row_array['cover'] = $row['cover'];
        $row_array['description'] = $row['description'];
        $row_array['playlists'] = array();  
        $row_array['tracks'] = array();  
        $plid = $row['idu'];

        $option_qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM playlists where playlists.by=$plid");
        while ($opt_fet = mysql_fetch_array($option_qry))
        {
            $row_array['playlists'][] = array(
                'id' => $opt_fet['id'],
                'name' => $opt_fet['name'],
                'by' => $opt_fet['by'],
            );


        }
        array_push($json_response, $row_array); //push the values in the array


        //tracks


        $option_qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tracks where tracks.uid=$plid");
        while ($opt_fet = mysql_fetch_array($option_qry))
        {
            $row_array['tracks'][] = array(
                'id' => $opt_fet['id'],
                'title' => $opt_fet['title'],
                'name' => $opt_fet['name'],
                'art' => $opt_fet['art'],
                'likes' => $opt_fet['likes'],
                'downloads' => $opt_fet['downloads'],
                'plays' => $opt_fet['views'],
                'uid' => $opt_fet['uid'],



            );


        }
        array_push($json_response, $row_array); //push the values in the array

    }
    echo json_encode($json_response,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
} // <-- WHY
?>
```

users Table:

```
id  username   last_name  first_name  country etc...
1   username1  Mynce      George      USA     etc...
2   username2  Jenkins    Fred        USA     etc...
3   username3  Walberg    Mark        USA     etc...
4   username4  Smith      Will        USA     etc...
```

playlists Table:

```
id   by  name
1    4   My playlists
2    3   Popular Songs
```

playlist entries Table:

```
id  playlists   track
12  1           13
13  1           23
14  1           3
15  1           17
16  1           9
12  2           14
13  2           24
14  2           4
15  2           18
16  2           10
```

tracks Table:

```
id  title      name      art      likes  downloads  views
1   song_title song1.mp3 art1.png 13     8          55
2   song_title song2.mp3 art2.png 12     10         31
3   song_title song3.mp3 art3.png 7      32         50
4   song_title song4.mp3 art4.png 22     11         1
5   song_title song5.mp3 art5.png 1      28         2
```

With my current code i am getting this JSON result:

```
{
        "idu": "2",
        "username": "chicagochurch",
        "first_name": "Chicago Christian Center",
        "last_name": "",
        "country": "United States",
        "image": "839674815_146358938_1746691162.png",
        "cover": "173157219_1187606488_302826016.jpg",
        "description": "This is the official Chicago Church Music page.",
        "playlists": [
            {
                "id": "4",
                "name": "We Give You Praise",
                "by": "2"
            }
        ],
        "tracks": []
    },
    {
        "idu": "2",
        "username": "chicagochurch",
        "first_name": "Chicago Christian Center",
        "last_name": "",
        "country": "United States",
        "image": "839674815_146358938_1746691162.png",
        "cover": "173157219_1187606488_302826016.jpg",
        "description": "This is the official Chicago Church Music page.",
        "playlists": [
            {
                "id": "4",
                "name": "We Give You Praise",
                "by": "2"
            }
        ],
        "tracks": [
            {
                "id": "29",
                "title": "01 We Give You Praise",
                "name": "1667450919_35711384_1898671201.mp3",
                "art": "97020012_1272964020_1490042512.png",
                "likes": "1",
                "downloads": "1",
                "plays": "5",
                "uid": "2"
            },
            {
                "id": "30",
                "title": "02 Luvudees",
                "name": "1361859314_884859216_209326964.mp3",
                "art": "1591964284_1156840179_1721104535.png",
                "likes": "1",
                "downloads": "1",
                "plays": "5",
                "uid": "2"
            },
            {
                "id": "31",
                "title": "03 Mugo Del",
                "name": "1366849477_130736941_1367659635.mp3",
                "art": "1181156184_556035815_1698596436.png",
                "likes": "0",
                "downloads": "1",
                "plays": "0",
                "uid": "2"
            },
            {
                "id": "32",
                "title": "04 San Amensa",
                "name": "40925819_971317614_1732715256.mp3",
                "art": "837149755_251638008_1945445596.png",
                "likes": "0",
                "downloads": "0",
                "plays": "1",
                "uid": "2"
            },
            {
                "id": "33",
                "title": "05 One True God",
                "name": "1201163785_1107025307_1077346045.mp3",
                "art": "713651840_1636034922_1247445482.png",
                "likes": "0",
                "downloads": "0",
                "plays": "0",
                "uid": "2"
            },
            {
                "id": "34",
                "title": "06 Mugo Anav",
                "name": "173569477_686122962_117960391.mp3",
                "art": "1432749408_578109445_1094716795.png",
                "likes": "0",
                "downloads": "0",
                "plays": "0",
                "uid": "2"
            },
            {
                "id": "35",
                "title": "07 Hallelujah",
                "name": "133051077_70993845_552471086.mp3",
                "art": "2040610215_1811023913_383444282.png",
                "likes": "0",
                "downloads": "0",
                "plays": "0",
                "uid": "2"
            },
            {
                "id": "36",
                "title": "08 Sheppard",
                "name": "984429058_1532916377_1375134853.mp3",
                "art": "1153269141_143559426_997684622.png",
                "likes": "0",
                "downloads": "0",
                "plays": "0",
                "uid": "2"
            },
            {
                "id": "37",
                "title": "09 I Love you Lord",
                "name": "794115968_1411878888_673035094.mp3",
                "art": "1692460167_1433248811_682631716.png",
                "likes": "0",
                "downloads": "0",
                "plays": "0",
                "uid": "2"
            },
            {
                "id": "38",
                "title": "10 Jesus In The Center",
                "name": "202390322_461558278_1271927584.mp3",
                "art": "1048499380_362527600_4599069.png",
                "likes": "0",
                "downloads": "1",
                "plays": "0",
                "uid": "2"
            },
            {
                "id": "39",
                "title": "11 Mugo Luvudeemos",
                "name": "274506373_302381815_356651583.mp3",
                "art": "1229728795_739090349_686501748.png",
                "likes": "0",
                "downloads": "1",
                "plays": "0",
                "uid": "2"
            },
            {
                "id": "40",
                "title": "12 Onday Chedo Kud",
                "name": "378498031_1470949688_1199351944.mp3",
                "art": "308978665_1074723934_419931699.png",
                "likes": "0",
                "downloads": "0",
                "plays": "0",
                "uid": "2"
            },
            {
                "id": "41",
                "title": "13 The Word",
                "name": "956461611_287666310_43661088.mp3",
                "art": "1584112229_240532531_977129308.png",
                "likes": "1",
                "downloads": "4",
                "plays": "0",
                "uid": "2"
            }
        ]
    }
```

**The JSON below is the structure i am trying to get, i want each playlist a user creates to nest the tracks associated with that playlist in a nested array under that playlists User>Playlists>Tracks**

*I typed out two playlists here "We Give You Praise" and "We Give You Praise 2" for example*

```
    {
        "idu": "2",
        "username": "chicagochurch",
        "first_name": "Chicago Christian Center",
        "last_name": "",
        "country": "United States",
        "image": "839674815_146358938_1746691162.png",
        "cover": "173157219_1187606488_302826016.jpg",
        "description": "This is the official Chicago Church Music page.",
        "playlists": [
            {
                "id": "4",
                "name": "We Give You Praise",
                "by": "2",
                "tracks": [
                    {
                        "id": "29",
                        "title": "01 We Give You Praise",
                        "name": "1667450919_35711384_1898671201.mp3",
                        "art": "97020012_1272964020_1490042512.png",
                        "likes": "1",
                        "downloads": "1",
                        "plays": "4",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "30",
                        "title": "02 Luvudees",
                        "name": "1361859314_884859216_209326964.mp3",
                        "art": "1591964284_1156840179_1721104535.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "1",
                        "plays": "3",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "31",
                        "title": "03 Mugo Del",
                        "name": "1366849477_130736941_1367659635.mp3",
                        "art": "1181156184_556035815_1698596436.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "1",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "32",
                        "title": "04 San Amensa",
                        "name": "40925819_971317614_1732715256.mp3",
                        "art": "837149755_251638008_1945445596.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "0",
                        "plays": "1",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "33",
                        "title": "05 One True God",
                        "name": "1201163785_1107025307_1077346045.mp3",
                        "art": "713651840_1636034922_1247445482.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "0",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "34",
                        "title": "06 Mugo Anav",
                        "name": "173569477_686122962_117960391.mp3",
                        "art": "1432749408_578109445_1094716795.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "0",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "35",
                        "title": "07 Hallelujah",
                        "name": "133051077_70993845_552471086.mp3",
                        "art": "2040610215_1811023913_383444282.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "0",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "36",
                        "title": "08 Sheppard",
                        "name": "984429058_1532916377_1375134853.mp3",
                        "art": "1153269141_143559426_997684622.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "0",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "37",
                        "title": "09 I Love you Lord",
                        "name": "794115968_1411878888_673035094.mp3",
                        "art": "1692460167_1433248811_682631716.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "0",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "38",
                        "title": "10 Jesus In The Center",
                        "name": "202390322_461558278_1271927584.mp3",
                        "art": "1048499380_362527600_4599069.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "1",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "39",
                        "title": "11 Mugo Luvudeemos",
                        "name": "274506373_302381815_356651583.mp3",
                        "art": "1229728795_739090349_686501748.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "1",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "40",
                        "title": "12 Onday Chedo Kud",
                        "name": "378498031_1470949688_1199351944.mp3",
                        "art": "308978665_1074723934_419931699.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "0",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "41",
                        "title": "13 The Word",
                        "name": "956461611_287666310_43661088.mp3",
                        "art": "1584112229_240532531_977129308.png",
                        "likes": "1",
                        "downloads": "4",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    }
                ]
            },
{
                "id": "5",
                "name": "We Give You Praise 2",
                "by": "2",
                "tracks": [
                    {
                        "id": "29",
                        "title": "01 We Give You Praise 2",
                        "name": "1667450919_35711384_1898671201.mp3",
                        "art": "97020012_1272964020_1490042512.png",
                        "likes": "1",
                        "downloads": "1",
                        "plays": "4",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "30",
                        "title": "02 Luvudees 2",
                        "name": "1361859314_884859216_209326964.mp3",
                        "art": "1591964284_1156840179_1721104535.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "1",
                        "plays": "3",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "31",
                        "title": "03 Mugo Del 2",
                        "name": "1366849477_130736941_1367659635.mp3",
                        "art": "1181156184_556035815_1698596436.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "1",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "32",
                        "title": "04 San Amensa 2",
                        "name": "40925819_971317614_1732715256.mp3",
                        "art": "837149755_251638008_1945445596.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "0",
                        "plays": "1",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "33",
                        "title": "05 One True God",
                        "name": "1201163785_1107025307_1077346045.mp3",
                        "art": "713651840_1636034922_1247445482.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "0",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "34",
                        "title": "06 Mugo Anav 2",
                        "name": "173569477_686122962_117960391.mp3",
                        "art": "1432749408_578109445_1094716795.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "0",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "35",
                        "title": "07 Hallelujah 2",
                        "name": "133051077_70993845_552471086.mp3",
                        "art": "2040610215_1811023913_383444282.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "0",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "36",
                        "title": "08 Sheppard 2",
                        "name": "984429058_1532916377_1375134853.mp3",
                        "art": "1153269141_143559426_997684622.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "0",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "37",
                        "title": "09 I Love you Lord 2",
                        "name": "794115968_1411878888_673035094.mp3",
                        "art": "1692460167_1433248811_682631716.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "0",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "38",
                        "title": "10 Jesus In The Center 2",
                        "name": "202390322_461558278_1271927584.mp3",
                        "art": "1048499380_362527600_4599069.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "1",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "39",
                        "title": "11 Mugo Luvudeemos 2",
                        "name": "274506373_302381815_356651583.mp3",
                        "art": "1229728795_739090349_686501748.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "1",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "40",
                        "title": "12 Onday Chedo Kud 2",
                        "name": "378498031_1470949688_1199351944.mp3",
                        "art": "308978665_1074723934_419931699.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "0",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "41",
                        "title": "13 The Word 2",
                        "name": "956461611_287666310_43661088.mp3",
                        "art": "1584112229_240532531_977129308.png",
                        "likes": "1",
                        "downloads": "4",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

as you can see in the above structure, the playlists is listing the tracks associated with it in its own nested array, I'm sure the playlistentries table will need to be used for this but I dont know how to implement it, Sorry for all the code... but thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you throw in a `{` for no aparent reason? You do appear to match it with a closing `}` but there is not reason for either.

Comment: @RiggsFolly the json example is just s snippet from the entire output http://gypsychristiannetwork.com/old_and_RnD/API/nested_json.php

Comment: No i mean in the first script you show

Comment: @RiggsFolly, im not sure what you mean... my writing skills are limited (hence I'm asking for some help here), i did just make a few edits to this post because i did update the code someone from what... but i am still not getting the results I'm looking for

Comment: See my temporoary edit, of first script you show

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes i see what your pointing out to... i dont know why those are there, maybe i didn't notice them after making some many changes, rearranging, copy and pasting snippets of code around

Comment: Basically you are adding things to the data structure that you eventually turn into JSON too early. Build a complete single instance of the datastructure then push it onto `$json_response` when its complete

Comment: @RiggsFolly that went over my head... can you show me?

Comment: @RiggsFolly how do i use the playlistsentries to populate the tracks nested user each playlists?... i think thats what i need to do, but do know how to approach it (or do it)... is that the way to go?

Comment: Check your database structure. It does not seem to support the idea of a USER has PLAYLISTS and a PLAYLIST has TRACKS. Without that structure in place there is no point going any further

Comment: @RiggsFolly PLAYLISTENTRIES can be connected to PLAYLISTS and PLAYLISTS to USER, i already connected PLAYLISTS to USER but i dont know how to connect TRACKS to PLAYLIST